# Can I fly into Korea but out of china?

Tags: visas

I plan to fly from Australia to Korea for a couple of weeks, then travel by ferry to Beijing for a few days.

My question is - instead of having to travel back to Seoul by ferry to fly home, can I just simply fly home from Beijing instead?

Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. Just think of it as two one-way flights.

However, due to the peculiarities of airline ticketing these two flights could well work out more expensive then if you fly all three legs of the journey.

Don't be tempted to book and not show up for the second leg. If you miss a flight the airline will cancel all subsequent legs.

Comment: An open-jaw ticket would probably be the OP's best bet here.  These are hard to book online, so talk with a travel agent.

Comment: *Don't be tempted to book and not show up for the second leg. If you miss a flight the airline will cancel all subsequent legs.* I don't understand this. Second leg of what, and what "subsequent legs" would be cancelled?

Comment: @MJeffryes Booking the three legs Australia-Korea, Korea-China, China-Australia could work out cheaper than booking just the first and last legs. Doing this and missing the Korea-China leg to take a ferry will result in cancellation of the China-Australia flight